# Filtering a List via a Sidebar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are two lists of items. One for your blog posts, and one for the authors.

```
var app = angular.module("Blog", []);

app.controller('PostCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.posts = <%= @posts.to_json.html_safe %>;
  $scope.authors = <%= @authors.to_json.html_safe %>;
});
```

The information is provided to us through a database via Rails. If you don't know Rails, assume that you have been given a big chunk of JSON to work with.

Now, we list the blog posts:

```
<div id="blog-posts" ng-controller="PostCtrl">
  <article class="post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h1> {{ post.title }} </h1>
    <small> By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.created_at }} </small>
    <p> {{ post.body }} </p>
  </article>
</div>
```

And then you decide to make an aside within the `#blog-posts` div (so that it is within the PostsCtrl) to list the authors:

```
<aside>
  <h2> Authors </h2>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="author in authors">
      {{ author.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Its nice that you're listing this and displaying the authors, but you also want to allow people to filter based on the author.

**Key Question**: How would one filter the blog posts when clicking on an author?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** when the user clicks on an author ([`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)), put the author in a variable, that you can then use to [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) the posts list.